# Windows clock is slow

Tags: windows-7, time

My windows 7 clock is slow by 3 minutes according to [this website](http://time.is/), and my android phone time.

I have tried manually syncing with the internet server and that does not fix. I went into date and time options, then the internet time tab.

It said

> This computer is set to automatically sync with "time.windows.com"

I then hit update now and it said

> An error occured while windows was synchronizing with
>   time.windows.com. This operatin returned because the timeout period
>   expired.

It gives the same error if I change to time.nist.gov

I can successfully ping time.nist.gov, but not time.windows.com

```
C:\>ping time.nist.gov

Pinging ntp1.glb.nist.gov [64.113.32.5] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 64.113.32.5: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=53
Reply from 64.113.32.5: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=53
Reply from 64.113.32.5: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=53
Reply from 64.113.32.5: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=53

Ping statistics for 64.113.32.5:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 53ms, Maximum = 53ms, Average = 53ms

C:\>ping time.windows.com

Pinging time.microsoft.akadns.net [40.118.103.7] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 40.118.103.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: "I have tried manually syncing with the internet server and that does not fix it" Please edit your question and expand on this to explain exactly what you tired (how, which time servers, etc.)

Comment: With that time server did you attempt to resync?
Was it automatically synchronizing always with internet servers, or was it disabled?
What is your time zone? 
What happens if you manually fix the time and reboot the machine?
Does the time gradually increases (could be a problem with the battery if so)?

Comment: Can you ping either of these domains?  You should provide specifics.

Comment: `ping time.windows.com` is not a useful diagnostic. It is likely that ICMP is disabled for this server.

Comment: Note the server is up and running.